# ++: does not appear to be right associative?

Tags: scala, syntactic-sugar, associativity

I am trying to learn scala.  I was looking at the documentation for queues (https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Queue.html).

It is my understanding that methods that end in a colon are right associative.  However, to me, the ++: does not apear to do so:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Queue
val q0 = Queue(0)
val q1 = Queue(1)
q0 ++ q1 // yields Queue(0,1) as I expected
q0 ++: q1 // yields Queue(0,1) as well;  I expected Queue(1,0)
```

Both the documentation and experimentation seem to indicate that ++: is not right associative.  The documentation for both ++ and ++: say left followed by the right and that is what happens above, I just don't understand why.  Clearly, there is something I am missing.  Could someone please clarify this for me?

Comment: Why would you expect different results? The documentation of the method clearly states that it gives the same result as `++:`. I'm too lazy to look it up, but I am assuming it is simply implemented as `def ++:(other) = other ++ this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple experiment:

```
case class A(s: String) { def ++:(a: A) = A(s"(${a.s} + ${s})") }
A("x") ++: A("y") ++: A("z")
```

gives:

```
A((x + (y + z)))
```

so it's `x + (y + z)` and not `(x + y) + z`. Thus, the `++:` is right-associative, as advertised.

Note that it's `${a.s} + ${s}` and not `${s} + ${a.s}`. In the case of `Queue`, it's probably analogous, something like:

```
def ++:(left: Queue[A]): Queue[A] = left ++ this
```

so the order of elements appears "as it should be" when you write `q0 ++: q1` which desugars into `q1.++:(q0)` and then expands into `q0 ++ q1`.

Comment: Thank you.  The last sentence is what clarified this for me.  I find it... interesting that it is right associative to q1 to start, but when you rewrite it in dot notation it becomes right associative to q0.  Since ++ and ++: appear to give identical results, when would you use one vs the other?

Comment: @WilliamAllcock The [code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.8/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L186) seems to be almost the same for `++` and `++:`, only the roles of `this` and `that` are flipped. So, the difference seems to be purely cosmetic. Maybe you might want to use `++:` when you want to emphasize that the queue on the right is something "big and stable", and the queue on the left is some "small increment". To be honest, I don't remember that I've ever used `++:` for anything.

Comment: Very confusing. The 2.13 docs say `++` is an alias for `concat` and `++:` is an alias for `prependedAll`. A quick inspection shows that prepending is expensive. It doesn't say that `concat` is an alias for `appendedAll`. The quick way to check parsing is `q0 ++: q1 //print<TAB>` in REPL.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I found this in the comments of the code link you gave above:     *  It differs from `++` in that the right operand determines the type of
   *  the resulting collection rather than the left one.
   *  Mnemonic: the COLon is on the side of the new COLlection type.

Comment: @WilliamAllcock Wellyeah... So, in the end of the day, what does it tell us? *"The type of the value returned by the method is determined by the return type of the method"*? True... Difficult to argue with that one. The mnemonic seems strange. Looks like something the author of the method came up with and then forgot ten minutes later.